# AngularGWT vs. GWTP

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, gwt, gwtp

There are different MVP frameworks which can be used for GWT.

[GWTP](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP) is one of them. The big advantage is that it is written entirely in Java and build on top of GWT.

[AngularGWT](https://github.com/cromwellian/angulargwt) is another MVP for GWT but it is a JSNI wrapper of the [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js) library.

**Can I use any performance benefits from GWT, when I use a MVP which is wrapping a JS library like AngularGWT is doing?**

Comment: I used GWTP, it is very good and structured way and simailar to GWT. GWT too have its own MVP architecture supporting framework included in it.I dont know about AngularGWt thanks for hearing first time from your post

Comment: It is funny that angularjs was introduced as some google devs found gwt frustrating and unproductive and now someone is doing the inverse

Comment: As far as i know JSNI calls and all GWT-wrapped javascript libs are  a bit slow, on the other side GWTP is a 100% GWT-based solution. Invest some time in it - GWTP is easy to understand and awesome to work with.

Comment: @РоманГуйван: could you post a source for your claims? How can JSNI calls be "a bit slow"? They are direct calls to Javascript libraries. There's no serialization, no conversion - just GWT Javascript code invoking other Javascript code.

Comment: Sorry, my previous statement is too misleading. What i ment is native javascript code and 3-d party libs whill not benefit from dead code optimization and other gwt compiler features.